# Having NA level for missing values with cut function from R

Tags: r, cut

The cut function in R omits NA. But I want to have a level for missing values. Here is my MWE.

```
set.seed(12345)
Y <- c(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 500, sd = 1), NA)
Y1 <-  cut(log(Y), 5)
Labs <- levels(Y1)
Labs

[1] "(6.21,6.212]"  "(6.212,6.213]" "(6.213,6.215]" "(6.215,6.217]" "(6.217,6.219]"
```

**Desired Output**

```
[1] "(6.21,6.212]"  "(6.212,6.213]" "(6.213,6.215]" "(6.215,6.217]" "(6.217,6.219]" "NA"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `addNA`

```
 Labs <- levels(addNA(Y1))
 Labs
#[1] "(6.21,6.212]"  "(6.212,6.213]" "(6.213,6.215]" "(6.215,6.217]"
#[5] "(6.217,6.219]" NA
```

In the expected output, you had character "NA".  But, I think it is better to have real NA as it can be removed/replaced with `is.na`

```
 is.na(Labs)
 #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Can we also append NA to Y1?

Comment: @MYaseen208  I'm sorry, I didn't get your comment.  `addNA(y1)` converts `y1` to a factor with NA as one of its levels.

Comment: It's okay @akrun. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the original MWE's third line to the following stores NA (actually ) in Y1 rather than the external vector Labs.  This cleans up analytic tasks like making tables or building models.  The NA is also still recognized by `is.na()`.

```
Y1 <-  factor(cut(log(Y), 5), exclude=NULL)
is.na(levels(Y1))
```

result:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```